# Why won't __add work?

Tags: lua

So I am trying to learn about metatables in lua, so i decided to follow some tutorials. I was trying out the __add part of metatables. But for some reason i kept on getting an error (attempt to perform arithmetic on field (nil)

```
aTable = {}
--Assign the values for the normal table 
for x = 1, 10 do 
    aTable[x] = x
end 

-- metatable
mt = {__add = function(table1, table2)
    sumTable = {}
    for i = 0, #table1 do
        sumTable[i] = table1[i] + table2[i]
    end
    return sumTable
end}


setmetatable(aTable, mt)

newTable = {}

newTable = aTable + aTable

for x = 1, #newTable do 
    print(newTable[x])
end
```

At this point i am confused.Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the __add-function it should be:

```
for i = 1, #table1 do
```

since you didn't set table[0] initially, but started at index 1 (which is indeed recommended for lua-pseudoarrays, many operations rely on it)

Comment: Ahhh Thanks so much! I was just to java's arrays which all start at 0

Answer (score 1):

@Ctx is correct that the problem is that differing indices in the array initialization and adding functions. But the best way to fix it is to modify your `__add` function to handle 'holes' in the arrays passed, by checking for nil entries in them.

```
  for i = 0, #table1 do
    if (table1[i] and table2[i]) then
      sumTable[i] = table1[i] + table2[i]
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I will try to use your advice

Answer (score 1):

Another thing that's missing: You don't set the same metatable on the result, which means that while things like `aTable+aTable`, `aTable+aTable+aTable` etc. will work, `aTable+aTable+(aTable+aTable)` will fail.

Corrected and cleaned version:

```
-- metatable
mt = {
    __add = function( table1, table2 )
        sumTable = {}
        for i = 1, #table1 do
            sumTable[i] = table1[i] + table2[i]
        end
        return setmetatable( sumTable, mt )
    end,
}

aTable = setmetatable( {}, mt )
--Assign the values for the normal table 
for x = 1, 10 do  aTable[x] = x  end 

newTable = aTable + aTable

for x = 1, #newTable do  print( newTable[x] )  end

-- and a test for what would have failed:
yetAnotherTable = newTable + newTable
for x = 1, #yetAnotherTable do  print( yetAnotherTable[x] )  end
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will definitely implement your advice in my future code!